# How to debug latency in Wi-Fi connection establishment to home router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I was visiting someone in the hospital for a few days (they are fine now) and the Wi-Fi connection worked instantly.

I would open my laptop and boom, connected within a few milliseconds. At home, the same laptop takes 30 seconds to connect to our Wi-Fi router. Where can I see what it's doing for those 30 seconds and make it work more like the instant-on hospital one?

Comment: Different OSes may have different behaviors. Exactly what OS are you running on that laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see what it's doing, you'll need an 802.11 monitor-mode packet trace. You also need it to capture the EAPOL key handshake (WPA2 PSK key handshake) so you can decrypt what the client is doing once it gets associated.

There are three basic things happening that you'll need to look at:

1. Scanning for the 802.11 network
2. Getting authenticated and connected at the 802.11 link layer
3. Getting a DHCP lease and/or doing IPv6 router discovery and SLAAC to get addresses, routes, and DNS server addresses set up.

**Factors affecting all three phases**

- Make sure you're close to your AP. Being too far from your AP can decrease bandwidth and increase latency and packet loss, which has much the same effect as dealing with an overloaded AP. See below.
- Make sure your AP is configured for the cleanest non-overlapping channel available. If the channel your AP is on is overloaded, it has much the same effect as the AP itself being overloaded. See below.
- Make sure your AP isn't overloaded with traffic, especially multicasts. Overloaded APs can take longer to respond to Probe Requests, making them harder to find. Overloaded APs can take longer to respond to the 802.11 authenticate, associate, and WPA2 PSK handshake packets, making it take longer to get connected. Overloaded APs can take longer to respond to DHCP requests or router solicitation packets, making it take longer to get your IP addresses set up.

**Scanning**
For fastest scans:

- Make sure you're broadcasting your SSID. That is, make sure you haven't told your AP to hide your network name. Hidden networks are harder to find in scans.
- Make sure your 5GHz network is on a non-DFS (non-radar) channel. Channels 52–144 are DFS channels, so make sure your 5GHz network is on 36–48 or 149–161. DFS channels are slower to scan because you're not allowed to transmit on them unless you've made sure there's no nearby radar operating on those frequencies, and that can take up to 60 seconds per channel. At the very least it takes an extra 60ms per channel, and there are lots of DFS channels.
- If your home AP is simultaneous dual-band, make sure you haven't turned off the 2.4GHz band. The 2.4GHz band is generally easier and faster to scan.
- If your Wi-Fi client software allows you to rank preferred networks, make sure your home network is at the top of the list.

**Getting Authenticated and Associated at the 802.11 Link Layer**

- I don't recommend that you disable WPA2-PSK, but realize that the hospital guest network probably didn't use any link-layer security, so it had the advantage of being able to skip this step. You may consider temporarily disabling wireless security as part of your troubleshooting process, but I recommend that you turn it back on after you're done troubleshooting.

**Getting a DHCP lease, etc.**

- Make sure your DHCP server isn't overloaded (in most home networks, your wireless router or your broadband modem/gateway is your DHCP server).
- Make sure your DNS servers respond quickly. Especially the first DNS server in the list. I could imagine a wireless client device not considering itself fully connected unless DNS works, and DNS clients usually try the DNS servers in listed order.

If you check/try all those things and still aren't getting on the network quickly, you'll have to get that packet trace and analyze it to see where the time is going.